# Ajax With Csrf Protection showing 403 forbidden in codeigniter 3.1.9

Tags: ajax, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am having issue while sending request to controller via ajax with csrf protection on. Its always gives an error as 403 forbidden. Facing this issue on localhost and on live server also. Using condeigniter 3.1.9

Following are my config values.

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = FALSE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array();
```

Ajax Code as Follow

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"http://localhost/Demo/products/getdata",
    dataType:'html',
    data:"char="+char,
    success: function(data){
        $('#proCatS').html(data);
    }
});
```

Please Help to solve this issue. Thanks !

Comment: You need to include the token in your `data` object, like `var csrfName = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>',
    csrfHash = '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>';`

Comment: You can use this example as well http://www.johnkieken.com/when-codeigniters-csrf-protection-breaks-your-ajax/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get csrf_token_name and csrf_hash code and pass these parameter in POST

```js
var csfrData = {
    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': 
         '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
};

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/Demo/products/getdata",
    data: {
        char: char, 
        csrf_test_name: csfrData
    },
    success: function(data) {
        $('#proCatS').html(data);
    }
});
```

Comment: hi, please try again, remove datatype as well

Comment: Hi . still after removing datatype its showing 403 forbidden error. Is there any parameter i need to set in config file